# Mobile safari shows location warning multiple times on the same site

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, location, geo

I am using geo.js in a mobile web application. I do a geo (zip) lookup on multiple pages of the web app.

My question: Only in mobile Safari (not an issue on Chrome for Android for instance), I get the "Do you want to allow..." location warning on every page that I do a geo lookup.

Shouldn't safari hold on to the granted permission and not ask again on the following pages of the web app?

Thanks.